# Can't send long buffers in Chrome via WebSockets

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, websocket

I'm trying to send the content of a 640 * 480 canvas to a WebSocket server.

The Javascript relevant part is here :

```
    // Get the image data
    var imageData = tCtx.getImageData (0, 0, 640, 480);
    var buf = imageData.data;
    var limit = buf.byteLength / 4;
    var buffer = new Uint8ClampedArray(921600);

    for (var i = 0; i < limit; ++i) {
        var originOffset = 4 * i;
        var targetOffset = 3 * i;

        buffer[targetOffset] = buf[originOffset + 2];
        buffer[targetOffset + 1] = buf[originOffset + 1];
        buffer[targetOffset + 2] = buf[originOffset];
    }

    // Send the data
    ws.send (buffer);
```

The for loop is simply to convert the RGBA format from the canvas to BGR for displaying the picture with OpenCV.

On Firefox it works and in my server I do get 921600 bytes received (I'm using libwebsockets) and I can even display the picture with OpenCV.
But on Chrome, the server doesn't receive the bytes and the WebSocket connection gets closed when I try to send this data.

I tried slicing the buffer before sending it, and I found out that the maximum I could send with Chrome was about 65000 bytes : i.e. when I try 70000 it doesn't work.

Any idea why ? And is there something I can do ? Will I have to manually slice the buffer and send the parts separtely ? I thought WebSockets was supposed to take care of that ?
Thanks in advance :-)